# When implementing the SOLID principles, should each usecase in Clean Architecture should the Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: node.js, clean-architecture

Since usecase in Clean Architecture is a place where we combine some logic to do specific business scenario, how about the single responsibility principle (SRP) when we implementing SOLID in our project? Does it not violate the SRP ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing A specific business scenariO. A single thing. So no - it does not violate it.